# Setting empty text instead of null to ng-model in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I need to get about 14 different input values from user to create a product and the input should not receive in the controller as `null` instead it should go as **empty string**

To achieve this the following is that I did:
**Controller:**

```
var NewProductCatalog = {
    CustomerGuid: '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000', SalesPartNo: "", Description: "",
    Name: "", Inventory: 0, UnitPrice: 0, BrandNo: "", TypeNo: "", LobNo: "", BrandName: "",
    TypeName: "", LobName: "", ManufacturePartNo: "", InventoryPartNo: "", EANCode: "",
    ImageURL: "", ProductType: "", DateAdded: "", Active: false, Tax: 0
};
$scope.newProductCatalog = NewProductCatalog;
```

**.cshtml:**

```
 <label for="SalesPartNo">Sales Part No *</label>
 <input type="text" required name="SalesPartNo" ng-model="newProductCatalog.SalesPartNo" class="form-control" />
 ...
 <input type="submit" ng-click="createProductCatalog(newProductCatalog)" />
```

**Create function(controller):**

```
$scope.createProductCatalog = function (NewProductCatalog) {
        var JsonString = angular.toJson(NewProductCatalog);
        CustomProductsServices.ProductCatalog_create(JsonString, function (callback) {
            if (callback.success) {
                $window.alert(callback.message);
            } else {
                $window.alert(callback.message);
            }
        });
    };
```

This allowed me to send an empty string when there user doesn't input any value.

**The issue:**
When I try to enter a value in a text box and then delete/empty the text box and submit. **I am not able to see the SalesPartNo in the resulting JSON string**

Please point out the error of if my approach is wrong suggest me a better approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please remove attribute required from `<input  name="SalesPartNo" />` as angularjs not binding to model unless value is valid.

Please demo here http://jsbin.com/wuhipe/1/edit?html,console,output

```
<input type="text"  name="SalesPartNo" ng-model="newProductCatalog.SalesPartNo" class="form-control" />
```

Comment: @RandomUser you can wrap your input into form and validate it before you send to server please see here http://jsbin.com/wuhipe/2/edit?console,output

Comment: @RandomUser please follow that example as you can see submit button not sending if form in not valid.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60958/discussion-between-sss-and-randomuser).

Answer (score 0):

You can extend JsonString using the default one, say, angular has extend method.
Make a copy of NewProductCatalog, say, NewProductCatalogCopy, and then do

```
angular.extend(NewProductCatalogCopy , JsonString);
```